# How to open and control a new tab TARGET _BLANK by click puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

there is a button that open a new tab (_blank) in browser, how do i reference this(like "await page2...") new tab and control it?

```
<button id="button" href="randomCode" target="_blank">BUTTON</button>
```

I tried use this in puppeteer:

```
await page1.waitForSelector('#button');
const link = await page1.$('#button');
const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.once('targetcreated', target => x(target.page())));
await link.click({button: 'left'});            
const page2= await newPagePromise;   
await page2.bringToFront();
```

But in this case, it only work to control sometimes (I don’t know why)

Note: The button link change with time, so it's necessary to click in the button/ can't close the first page.

Comment: could you please more explanation about " reference this new tab and control it"? what is your expectation?

Comment: sure, reference it mean to control it, so, when i type "page2.goto", I'm referencing this page2, and controlling it.

Comment: * when i type "page2.goto"*, where do you type?

Comment: it's just an exemple, i mean to control with a reference, the reference is "page2", or "pagetwo" dont matter, got it? It's veryyy difficult to found the answer

Answer (score 0):

If there is someone with the same error, I found the solution, get the href of button, and then, open a new tab with the href:

```
const hrefs1 = await page.evaluate(
  () => Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('a[SELECTOR]'),
    a => a.getAttribute('href')
  )
);

const pagina2 = await browser.newPage();
await pagina2.goto(''+hrefs1);
```

There is no error in this case.